# Euler Project 47 finding all numbers contaning 4 factors

Tags: python, math, optimization

I first create a list of 10^6 false values and what I want to do is to iterate True over the interval for all numbers containing 4 distinct prime factors.

What that means is that the number 2 * 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 is a number containing 4 distinct prime numbers.

I really have no clue how to create the numbers, I don't even know how to think of the it. I want to have 4 different kinds of numbers but in all possible different amounts. Code as far:

```
""" Pre do prime list """

sieve = [True] * 1000
sieve[0] = sieve[1] = False

def primes(sieve, x):
for i in range(x+x, len(sieve), x):
    sieve[i] = False

for x in range(2, int(len(sieve) ** 0.5) + 1):
primes(sieve, x)

PRIMES = list((x for x in range(2, len(sieve)) if sieve[x]))

""" Main """

Numbers = [False] * 10 ** 6

Factors = PRIMES[0] * PRIMES[1] * PRIMES[2] * PRIMES[3]
Numbers[Factors] = True

for prime in PRIMES:
    for prime in PRIMES[1:]:
        for prime in PRIMES[2:]:
            for prime in PRIMES[3:]:
```

Comment: Why don't you brute force it? That's what I did and it worked.

Comment: It's to slow. And this is to interesting.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong then. Perhaps not making the correct optimizations?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to keep track of how many prime factors you have found for each number. You can perform the Sieve of Eratosthenes, but instead of marking multiples of a prime as composite, increment the count of primes dividing them. Make sure that you use an unoptimized loop: Once you choose the prime p, increment the count of primes dividing p, 2*p, 3*p etc. instead of marking p^2, p^2+2*p, etc. composite.

Another possibility is to record the smallest prime factor of each number as you perform the Sieve of Eratosthenes. This lets you find the prime factorization recursively, and you can check which of these have exactly 4 prime factors.

Comment: ... and there was light.

Answer (score 0):

could you do it the other way round: get a list of primes up to root(N) then generate products that are less than N. Something like:

```
res = {}
for i in range(n):
  for j in range(i,n):
    for k in range(j,n):
      for m in range(k,n):
        prod = p[i] * p[j] * p[k] * p[m]
        if prod < N:
          res[prod] = [p[i], p[j], p[k], p[m]]
```

ed. just noticed `distinct` so you would have to put each p[] ** u and iterate each over a suitable number with another four nested loops! Probably still faster to do it this way round.

PPS after a little thought, the above method will be significantly slower than just using the modified sieve as suggested by Douglas Zare. By the time I get to 10**6 my first suggestion takes minutes but the modified sieve is less than 10s

```
class Numb(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.is_prime = True
    self.pf = []

  def tick(self, factor):
    self.is_prime = False
    self.pf.append(factor)

N = 1000000
sieve = [Numb() for i in range(N)]
sieve[0].is_prime = sieve[1].is_prime = False

def primes(sieve, x):
  for i in range(x + x, len(sieve), x):
    sieve[i].tick(x)

for x in range(2, int(len(sieve) ** 0.5) + 1):
  if sieve[x].is_prime:
    primes(sieve, x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I continued doing something like this, before trying out sieve method.. And in the end realising that I should use an search algorithm that finds two odd number with 4 distinct factors which differ by 2 and try the number in-between and the number before and after. if this condition is meet the problem is solved.

It's actually falls back on the same problem as stated in post but through some number-theory magic reduces to just finding numbers with no multiples of factors where question conditions is meet.

```
Factors = list([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2]) + [0] * 5 * 10 ** 5

for prime in PRIMES:
    Factors[prime] = 1

for number in range(10, 5 * 10 ** 5):
    if Factors[number] == 1:
        continue
    for prime in PRIMES:
        if number % prime == 0:
            Factors[number] = Factors[prime] + Factors[number // prime]
            break
```

Comment: It's still kinda cheating for I presume to know the value of the greatest prime factor in the odd numbers.