# Find the number that has 4 distinct prime factors

Tags: java, prime-factoring

Get the number n from the user.Then print the nth number that has at-least 4 distinct prime factors. Eg(210 prime factors(2,3,5,7) ) 210 is the first number that is having 4 distinct prime factors the next number is 330(2,3,5,11).
Input:2 output:330 and Input:3 output:390.I don't know how to do this?I tried to find the prime factors for a number.

```
 for (int i = 2; i <= number; i++) {
     while (number % i == 0) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
        number = number / i;
     }
 }
 if (number < 1) 
     System.out.println(number);
```

But i want to print the nth number that has 4 distinct prime factors.

Comment: Break the problem into smaller sub-problems, and then figure out which sub-problem you don't know how to solve. After you identify that, you should do some research on how to solve it.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. You wrote: _Get the number n from the user._ And you also wrote: _Input:2 output:330_ Does this mean the user enters _2_ and the program prints _330_ ?

Comment: That is Euler-Problem #47.
https://projecteuler.net/problem=47 and has been solved on stackoverflow here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29616115/euler-project-47-finding-all-numbers-contaning-4-factors

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Euler Project 47 finding all numbers contaning 4 factors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29616115/euler-project-47-finding-all-numbers-contaning-4-factors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following code:

```
public static boolean findPrimeFactors(int n) {
    Set<Integer> primeFactorSet = new HashSet<>();
    while (n % 2 == 0) {
        // here number is even so adding 2
        primeFactorSet.add(2);
        n /= 2;
    }

    // number would be odd in this loop
    for (int i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i += 2) {
        while (n % i == 0) {
            primeFactorSet.add(i);
            n /= i;
        }
    }

    if (n > 2) {
        primeFactorSet.add(n);
    }

    // true if the unique prime-factors are greater than or equal to 4
    return primeFactorSet.size() >= 4 ? true : false;
}
```

Now invoke it using:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> primeFactorList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    // accept this from user
    int n = 2;

    for (int i = 210;; i++) {
        // find prime factors for each number
        if (findPrimeFactors(i)) {
            primeFactorList.add(i);
        }
        if (primeFactorList.size() == n) {
            System.out.println(primeFactorList.get(n - 1));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Explanation:

1. The loop iterates from 210 till the nth number that has four or more
   different prime factors.
2. For every number that *meets* the criteria, the method returns true else false.
3. Next a check is made to see if the size of the list is equal to the
   number (`n`) entered by the user. If its equal the `n-1`th
   index is fetched and the loop is exited.

Comment: What is the reason of using i <= Math.sqrt(n) in odd for loop?Could you please explain?

Comment: Because it prevents duplicate divisions.  Consider `100/ 5 = 20`.  There is no sense to then see if `100 is divisible by 20` because it was already encountered since `5 * 20  == 100`.  So there is no point in going beyond the square root.

Comment: @Harini: Every composite number has a prime factor that is smaller than the square root, and the loop only cares about the smallest. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63276/

Comment: Actually the sqrt() method is expensive and should only be called again when n has changed. However I tested and it seems the compiler does this optimization automatically in this case.

Answer (score 0):

One problem with the above method is that it divides by all odd numbers up to the square root of the candidate. It would be better to divide by previously accumulated primes. That is easily done as follows:

```java
      List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>(List.of(2));
      outer:
      for (int i = 3; i < n; i++) {
         int end = (int)Math.sqrt(i);
         for (int k = 0, p = primes.get(0); p <= end; p =
               primes.get(k++)) {
            if (i % p == 0) {
               continue outer;
            }
         }
         primes.add(i);
      }
```

And move the square root calculation out of the loop. It is evaluated on every cycle.